# C++: Assigning a function to a tr1::function object

Tags: c++, delegates, tr1

One of our classes provides tr1::function callback object. When I try assigning a member function to it, though, I get a compiler error.

The examples below are untested and just to illustrate:

Foo.h:

```
class Foo()
{
public:
  Foo();
  std::tr1::function<void (int x)> F;
}
```

Bar.h:

```
class Bar()
{
public:
   Bar();
   Foo* foo;
   void HookUpToFoo();
   void Respond(int x);
}
```

Bar.cpp:

```
Bar()
{
    this->foo = new Foo();
    this->HookUpToFoo();
}

void Bar::HookUpToFoo()
{
  this->foo->F = &Bar::Respond; // error
}

void Bar::Respond(int x)
{
       // do stuff
}
```

The compiler error we get refers to a line in xrefwrap and is
Error   1   error C2296: '.*' : illegal, left operand has type 'int'    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xrefwrap    64

..What am I doing wrong in assigning a delegate? I want to go the more modern route and use tr1::function rather than function pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A member function accepts an additional hidden parameter: `this`. This makes it incompatible with your `function` object which only accepts one parameter. You can bind a member function to a particular instance using `bind`, which is also available in `tr1`:

```
using namespace std::tr1::placeholders;

this->foo->F = std::tr1::bind(&Bar::Respond, this, _1);
```

This ensures that `Bar::Respond` will be called with the correct value bound to `this`. The `_1` is a placeholder for the additional parameter (`x`).

Comment: Or simply `std::tr1::bind(&Bar::Respond, this)`, without the placeholder.

Comment: @Alexandre: It doesn't work for me without the placeholder: http://www.ideone.com/k3VD9

Comment: Thanks, interjay, it works when I use bind rather than assign with =. Note: I also had to use the placeholder, it didn't compile otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`Bar::Respond` is a member function, not a function.  It cannot be called without a `this`.  This is the same as the difference between a `void (Bar::*)(int)` member function pointer and a `void (*)(int)` function pointer.

You can use `mem_fn` to create a `function` object from a member function.

```
F = std::bind1st(std::tr1::mem_fn(&Bar::Respond), this);
```